# Exponential sums reference

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, exponential-sum, reference-works

Looking for reference on exponential sums, in particular Jacobi, Gauss, Kloosterman and Ramanujan sums. The books mentioned in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/65429/exponential-sums-for-beginner  are at a higher level than I understand, however I have read Tom Apostols analytic number theory book, so I would like a reference at that level or above.

Comment: Exponential sums in general are not treated, but Gauss and Ramanujan sums are treated

Comment: A bit surprised to see that Apostol doesn't mention Jacobi sums.

Comment: He does, but as I said I’ve read the book anyway

Comment: Possibly Davenport's book on Multiplicative Number Theory, or Montgomery and Vaughan's book on Multiplicative Number Theory. I would expect at the very least that after reading Montgomery and Vaughan, one should be able to read Graham and Kolesnik (as mentioned at MO), which is a classical reference.